# Cannot install Intel Graphics Driver on Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, intel-graphics

I am trying to update Intel Graphics Driver, but I get this error:

[image: Intel Graphics Error]

Answer (score 6):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo xed /etc/lsb-release
```

Edit your file as follow:

```
#DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
#DISTRIB_RELEASE=18
#DISTRIB_CODENAME=sarah
#DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18 Sarah"
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
```

Save and exit.

Update and run the installer:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Edit the file again:

```
sudo xed /etc/lsb-release
```

and revert changes:

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sarah
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18 Sarah"
#DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
#DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
#DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
#DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
```

Save and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for replying but this seems not to be a problem with the distribution, as it said : "E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

Answer (score 6):

1. Run the following command:

   ```
   wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-GROUP-KEY-ilg

   sudo apt-key add RPM-GPG-GROUP-KEY-ilg
   ```
2. Afterwards you may run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

This is the fix for the signature problems with the Intel installer [Source](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.3).